# collectionViewLayout with items aligned to the left in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

I have a collectionView with images from a service request that are showed in lines with 3 elements.
What I need is that when a Have just one or two images from the request, the images shows aligned to the left, but the screen shows the images centered.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if imageFuelArray.count == 1{
            let padding: CGFloat =  10
            let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
            let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.frame.size.height - padding
            
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewHeight)
        } else{
            let padding: CGFloat =  10
            let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
            let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.frame.size.height - padding
            
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/2, height: collectionViewHeight/2)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this function

```
func getSizeVews(){
         if imageFuelArray.count > 6{
            self.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.collectionView.contentSize.height+45).isActive = true
                              self.servicesTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.servicesTableView.contentSize.height+70).isActive = true
                              
                              view.layoutSubviews()
         } else {
            self.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.collectionView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
                   self.servicesTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.servicesTableView.contentSize.height+70).isActive = true
                   
                   view.layoutSubviews()
        }
       
    }
```

And there I have my collectionView datasource and delegate

```
extension ServicesStationViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        imageFuelArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: flCollectionVieCell, for: indexPath) as! FuelCollectionViewCell
        let fuel = imageFuelArray[indexPath.row]
        
        if let cepsaFuel = CepsaFeaturesFuel(key: Int(fuel) ?? 0) {
            let imgName = CepsaFeaturesFuel.featureFuelImageName(with: cepsaFuel.featuresFuelType)
            
            cell.fuelImageView?.image = UIImage(named: imgName!)
        }
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if imageFuelArray.count == 1{
            let padding: CGFloat =  10
            let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
            let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.frame.size.height - padding
            
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewHeight)
        } else{
            let padding: CGFloat =  10
            let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
            let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.frame.size.height - padding
            
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/2, height: collectionViewHeight/2)
        }
    }
    
}
```